# Selenium docker - chrome standalone does not work

Tags: javascript, selenium, docker

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5901:5900 --shm-size=2g selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.9.1-actinium

mocha Test.js
```

http://0.0.0.0:4444/ and looking at console screenshot shows docker chrome debug mode test ran as expected.

But docker chrome standalone does not work.

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size=2g selenium/standalone-chrome:3.9.1-actinium

mocha Test.js
```

The test starts but hangs. No errors. I am running this on my Mac.

```
var options = new chrome.Options();
options.setUserPreferences({ credentials_enable_service: false });
         browser = new webdriver.Builder()
        .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
        .withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'})
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in interactive mode (--it) iso (-d) and see what it tells you when running?

Comment: @Ivonet - It shows the first step of configure browser worked. I don't know why it was showing as failed if I did not use the -it option. I ran it as: docker run -itd -p 4444:4444 -p 5901:5900 --shm-size=2g selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.9.1-actinium. Thanks this helped.